# How can i install my package automatically on docker container

Tags: save, package, docker, linux-containers

I have to create three container and i have to installed package automatically on this container? 
How can i do that?

I need save docker file.

Thanks for help by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic knowledge**

So, read official guideline https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/ and write your own `Dockerfile` to automate your installation of your packages in your container.

**Reuse existing docker images**

docker is built on community as well, before you write your Dockerfile, you may check the http://hub.docker.com to reuse exsiting one or take them as examples

Comment: Thanks for this, i go to check that,if i understand well i pull an image and i build this image like i want (memory limit, comande to launch ...) Can I build more one dockerfile.